# rails change initializer config value runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is a generic question, but i failed to find an answer even after spending hours, any help is appreciated.
Is there a way to change the config values stored in initializer during run time, i have setting like this in config/initializers/cardconnect.rb

```
CardConnect.configure do |config|
   config.api_username = 'cardconnect1'
end
```

how do i access the api_username variable and change it in controller?

Thanks

this is the gem i am using : https://github.com/mobilecause/cardconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick skim of the source code, the underlining of connection used in `CardConnect` is a singleton, and initilized with the configed value in `CardConnect.configuration`.

You can update the config with

```
CardConnect.configuration.api_username = 'xxx'
```

before using any `CardConnect` api.

And use `CardConnect.configuration.api_username` to read the current value.

Answer (score 1):

Access it like so `CardConnect.configuration` and change it like so: `CardConnect.configuration.api_username = 'honestCorp'`.